# How can I change the structure of this type in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

My apologies, I don't speak English and i am a beginner in javascript and i have a problem.

I have this :

```
[
    {
        nombre: "Juan",
        edad: 23,
        type: "seccion"
    },
    {
        nombre: "Miguel",
        edad: 30,
        typo: "e"
    },
    {
        nombre: "Claudio",
        edad: 22,
        type: "b"
    },
    {
        nombre: "Antonio",
        edad: 33,
        type: "seccion"
    },
    {
        nombre: "Angela",
        edad: 44,
        type: "rr"
    },
    {
        nombre: "Norberto",
        edad: 27,
        type: "xx"
    } ]
```

And i would like this :

```
[
    {
        nombre: "Juan",
        edad: 23,
        type: "section",
        items: [
            {
                nombre: "Miguel",
                edar: 30,
                typo: "e"
            },
            {
                nombre: "Claudio",
                edar: 22,
                typo: "bbbb"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        nombre: "Antonio",
        edad: 33,
        type: "section",
        items:[
            {
                nombre: "Angela",
                edar: 44,
                typo: "rr"
            },
            {
                nombre: "Norberto",
                edar: 27,
                typo: "xx"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As you can see, I need to group object type elements that do not have the type property with value "section" within the elements with the value equal to "section"

Comment: What determines which _section_ element the non-section elements go in to? Why do Miguel and Cluadio go into the Juan section and not the Antonio section?

Comment: Normal protocol is to make an attempt at solving it yourself before asking. See [mcve] and [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: excuse me, the clarification is at the end of the publication of the question. As for testing, they were pure rubbish, I was too far away from a solution, so I didn't put them on, in short, they didn't bring anything :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

There are some discrepancies in your original array, e.g. `typo` -> `type`, `seccion` -> `section`

I assume those are typos and only using `type` and `section` for consistency or it won't work.

```js
const data = [
    {
        nombre: "Juan",
        edad: 23,
        type: "section"
    },
    {
        nombre: "Miguel",
        edad: 30,
        type: "e"
    },
    {
        nombre: "Claudio",
        edad: 22,
        type: "b"
    },
    {
        nombre: "Antonio",
        edad: 33,
        type: "section"
    },
    {
        nombre: "Angela",
        edad: 44,
        type: "rr"
    },
    {
        nombre: "Norberto",
        edad: 27,
        type: "xx"
    }
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (cur.type === 'section') {
        acc.push({ ...cur, items: [] });
    } else {
        acc[acc.length - 1].items.push(cur)
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

> Do mind the first element has to be a `section` or it will throw an error.